# How to use Google Workbox with Next.js?

Tags: service-worker, next.js, workbox

I have an Next.js app that's currently using sw-precache and sw-precache-webpack-plugin to generate a service worker.

I would like to migrate to use Google Workbox and workbox-webpack-plugin instead. Has anyone successfully done that in a Next.js context?

Answer (score 1):

[next-offline](https://github.com/hanford/next-offline) seems to be the standard here. It "just works".

Answer (score 0):

Someone creates this plugin, could be better(because I will need to fork it to include my css in the cache), but is fine for this.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-workbox-webpack-plugin